# How to use deployed webservice of Microsoft Azure in my web application using java

Tags: java, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have done an experiment in Microsoft Azure Machine learning and deployed a web service . Now i want to use this web service from my web application in java  So that i sent data to web service and it will return analytics report. But i don't know ho to use this deployed webservice so kindly help me.
please sent a suitable example which works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic.  You should show what you've tried, what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no need to have the tutorial etc. In the WebService pane in your Workplace, choose your webservice, then, inside of that, you should have the whole page full of code examples that are set up for your webservice.

Useful pages:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-consume-web-services/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-consume-web-service-with-web-app-template/

Answer (score 0):

There are two guideline articles as sample can help you how to get started, not code sample.

1. [Connect to an Azure Machine Learning Web Service](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/machine-learning-connect-to-azure-machine-learning-web-service.md)
2. [Consume an Azure Machine Learning web service with a web app template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/machine-learning-consume-web-service-with-web-app-template.md)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample java code - https://github.com/nk773/AzureML_RRSApp. This requires [Apache HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

```
        try {
        // create HttpPost and HttpClient object
        if (post == null){
            post = new HttpPost(apiurl);
            client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        }

        // setup output message by copying JSON body into 
        // apache StringEntity object along with content type
        entity = new StringEntity(jsonBody, HTTP.UTF_8);
        entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
        entity.setContentType("text/json");


        // add HTTP headers
        post.setHeader("Accept", "text/json");
        post.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

        // set Authorization header based on the API key
        post.setHeader("Authorization", ("Bearer "+apikey));
        post.setEntity(entity);


        post.setHeader(HTTP.CONN_DIRECTIVE,HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE);

        System.out.println();
        HttpResponse authResponse=null;
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Call REST API and retrieve response content
        authResponse = client.execute(post);
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(t2-t1);

        //}

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        return e.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer  actually now i successfully consume the deployed web service of Azure by using following link                   https://github.com/nk773/AzureML_RRSApp](https://github.com/nk773/AzureML_RRSApp